# Temporary Webview Android

Tags: android, webview, addition, temporary

Greetings.

I would like to have my application have a function so that when the user chooses, a web view will pop up they can look at it and then dismiss it by either pressing a button on the screen or the back button.  How would I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `Activity` containing your `WebView` and all the other stuff you need and have that `Activity` be started through an `Intent`. When the user is done with doing stuff in the `WebView` just let him press the back button and you're fine.

Comment: How can I send the URL I need into the Activity efficiently?

Comment: Package it as the "data" of the `Intent` via `setData()`. The receiving activity would retrieve it via `getIntent().getData()`.

Comment: Awesome!  Works flawlessly so far.

Comment: One more question, If I wanted to send a string into the Intent, what code would I use?

Comment: In that case use the Intent extras using the `putExtra()` method to set the extra and `getExtra()` method to retrieve it. Check the reference page on [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for more information about those classes.

Answer (score 1):

You just create an activity that contains a webview with the url you need and then you intercept the url clicks and react accordingly in your app.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html